# Org-journal create a new bullet with timestamp within the existing journal entry

Tags: org-mode

If I create a new org-journal entry, the entry will open with an Org-mode bullet and a timestamp. If I already have a journal entry open though, is there a way to add a new bullet and timestamp from within the entry? I did not see any mention of that, but I figure it would not be very hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I press C-c ! to run org-time-stamp-inactive to add a timestamp. That may be bound for you. Preface it with a C-u to get the time in addition to the date.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that is the simplest way. I was hoping that there was a function that would create a new timestamp each time I pushed C-Enter to create a new bullet in the org-journal. But I can live with the C-c ! or in my case C-u C-c . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I understand this question is almost an year old, but since it may help someone in future, I'm adding my answer

`M-x org-journal-new-entry` does this exact thing for me.

e.g. If I had a file for today's journal with single timestamp bullet (say at `11:00`) then calling `M-x org-journal-new-entry` next time, will just add new timestamp bullet (for the current time) to the existing file.

Just for testing, I called `M-x org-journal-new-entry` in rapid succession (within same minute) so two entries (for say `11:00`) were created. (I had expected that it will **not** create second bullet, but ..)